# Сохранение XML файла по указанному пути

Tags: python, xml

```
XML_FILE = os.path.join(path, fileName)

tree = ET.ElementTree(file = XML_FILE)

...some actions with xml file...

tree.write(fileName, encoding = "UTF-8", xml_declaration = True)
```

Как указать по какому именно пути нужно сохранять файл?

Answer (score 0):

Укажите его в переменной fileName

Например:

```
fileName = "D:\work\1.xml"
```

Comment: Дай бог тебе здоровья!